# ClassNotFoundException with Jackson on plugin disable

Tags: java, maven, jackson, build-tools, spigot

I'm making a spigot plugin and in the onDisable function (which gets called when the server shuts down) I have it save my data. The problem is is that when it disables for some reason it cannot find one of the classes (ObjectWriter) that I use to save the data.[image: Traceback of the error, says that the class cannot be found]

However as shown in the following screenshot that class is very much there and very much present, which can also be proven by the fact that I can save it normally and it works just fine. It is only when the plugin disables that I have this issue.[image: Shows the inside of the jar file, the path on the top shows where the class is located and it shows the class in the correct package]

I've been trying to fix this issue for months. Yes, I have tried running `mvn clean`. Yes, I have tried deleting the dependency jar in case it's corrupted. I have scoured SO since I had the problem and tried every. single. post. None of them have worked. I don't think this is a problem with maven more than it is a problem with the dependencies closing before the plugin finishes, because sometimes it *does* work and *doesn't* error. It's extremely confusing to me and I have no idea what to do.

Here is my pom.xml if anyone wants to review it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.uhmily</groupId>
    <artifactId>scovilleplugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ScovillePlugin</name>

    <description>The Main Plugin for the Scoville Parkour Server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.nms.path>C:/Users/depia/Documents/My_Stuff/Programs/Minecraft/spigot-1.12.jar</project.nms.path>
        <project.mainClass>ScovillePlugin</project.mainClass>
        <jackson.version>2.13.1</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <!-- <include>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind</include>
                                    <include>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core</include>
                                    <include>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations</include> -->
                                    <include>com.fasterxml.jackson.*:*</include>
                                    <include>de.tr7zw:*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <relocations>
                                <!-- <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.core</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson.databind</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind</shadedPattern> -->
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>de.tr7zw.changeme.nbtapi</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}.shaded.de.tr7zw.changeme.nbtapi</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/**</exclude>
                                        <exclude>module-info.class</exclude>
                                        <exclude>LICENSE</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}.${project.mainClass}</Main-Class>
                                        <Build-Number>${project.version}</Build-Number>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>enginehub</id>
            <url>https://maven.enginehub.org/repo/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>plotsquared</id>
            <url>https://plotsquared.com/mvn/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>placeholderapi</id>
            <url>http://repo.extendedclip.com/content/repositories/placeholderapi/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>codemc-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.codemc.org/repository/maven-public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sk89q-repo</id>
            <url>https://maven.enginehub.org/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven-snapshot</id>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>23.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minecraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>server</artifactId>
            <version>v1.12</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.nms.path}</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.plotsquared</groupId>
            <artifactId>plotsquared-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.clip</groupId>
            <artifactId>placeholderapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.tr7zw</groupId>
            <artifactId>item-nbt-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sk89q.worldguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>worldguard-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sk89q.worldedit</groupId>
            <artifactId>worldedit-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.luckperms</groupId>
            <artifactId>api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found out due to [this post](https://bukkit.org/threads/ondisable-throws-classnotfoundexception.182811/) that this happens when you replace the jar file before shutting down the server. This would explain all of the behavior I've been experiencing.